# IBM Watson NLU: How to determine remaining credits via API Endpoint?

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I am using a Free plan for IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding. I'd like to check the remaining credits of my plan for the given resource with a single API call.

I've seen something like [Get credit pools](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/enterprise-apis/billing-unit#get-credit-pools) in the IBM Cloud docs, but I am not able to determine my `billing_unit_id` which is required to make the request. Is this even doable for a Free plan? If so, could you help me with where to find a `billing_unit_id` or redirecting me to another API Endpoint (that hopefully has a cURL example) so I could check remaining credits of my NLU instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you referred to is part of the [billing and sage API for so-called Enterprises](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/billing-usage?topic=billing-usage-enterprise). An [IBM Cloud enterprise](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-what-is-enterprise) is comparable to a meta account which allows to manage a hierarchy of accounts and account groups. It is not available for free and regular accounts and is unrelated to NLU usage.

What you are looking for is a way to see your usage for the [IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-about) service. [The usage in NLU items is returned in each API response](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-pricing#nlu-items).

For total usage reporting, you should check out the **Billing and usage** section in your account. There you can drill down. If you then have identified details, look into the [usage reporting API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/metering-reporting) or the [CLI commands](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_billing).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! I understand that I can track usage for a single API call, but I need a way to check total usage state related to that instance so I can take action before it maxes out. To be more specific, the data shown in this image: https://i.imgur.com/faBmI1k.png  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I added to the answer, pointing to the API that you could use.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks! I keep getting `"message": "Authorization failed"` in response even though I have a fresh IAM Token, I am the owner of the account with `All account management services` role in Access policies and I've used the Account ID from the Account Settings. Could I be missing something?

Comment: make sure that `Bearer` is part of the token part

Comment: It actually is included. Here is how my cURL looks: https://pastebin.com/GEJn0UrM

Comment: Just to make sure: You use an IBM Cloud platform token, not one for the NLU service, right? On the command line, use `ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens` to get a fresh token

Comment: This was it, thanks! Now it works perfectly.